# Animation not working properly on IE11

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, animation

I have an animation that is working properly on the rest of the browsers but IE11.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.activate').click(function() {
    $('.eight-box').toggleClass('animate')
  });
}());
```

```css
.activate {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.eight-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fig-8 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  background: black;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.rotate1,
.rotate2,
.rotate3,
.rotate4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rotate1 .pos-4,
.rotate2 .pos-4,
.rotate3 .pos-4,
.rotate4 .pos-4 {
  top: 0;
  left: -35px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-19deg);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rotate1,
.rotate2,
.rotate3,
.rotate4 {
  transform: rotate(19deg);
}

.animate .rotate4 {
  animation: circularAnimation-a 1s 1s 1 forwards;
}

.animate .rotate4 .pos-4 {
  animation: positioning-a 1s 1s 1 both, pulse 1s 3s 1 alternate forwards;
}

.animate .rotate3 {
  animation: circularAnimation-b 1s 1s 1 forwards;
}

.animate .rotate3 .pos-4 {
  transform: rotate(-220deg);
  animation: pulse 1s 3s 1 alternate forwards;
}

.animate .rotate2 {
  animation: circularAnimation-c 1s 1s 1 forwards;
}

.animate .rotate2 .pos-4 {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  animation: pulse 1s 3s 1 alternate forwards;
}

.animate .rotate1 .pos-4 {
  animation: pulse 1s 3s 1 alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes positioning-a {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-19deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(190deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-a {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(19deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-190deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-b {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(19deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-140deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-c {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(19deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
  }
}

@keyframes positioning-b {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(23deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-d {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(23deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-e {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(23deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-f {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(23deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
}

@keyframes positioning-c {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(150deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-g {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-150deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circularAnimation-h {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-55deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="activate">Animate</button>
<div class="eight-box">
  <div class="rotate1">
    <div class="fig-8 col-1 pos-4">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotate2">
    <div class="fig-8 col-2 pos-4">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotate3">
    <div class="fig-8 col-3 pos-4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rotate4">
    <div class="fig-8 col-4 pos-4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is with SCSS which is what I am using in my project: https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/NgBZZL

The animation works awesome on Chrome and Firefox, but IE11 has some glitches which are the same you may look when you toggle the class .animate in the second try.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check if `$(document).ready()` is working on IE11.
I think it is not really working. you can check it by logging on it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("loaded");
})
```